# Synchronise two tracks by BPM in Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html

I can get two tracks playing at the same time but because they have different BPM it sounds pretty bad... Is there a way to synchronise the BPM for both tracks without affecting the pitch?

Comment: Do you know any info of the BPM from each track? If not there is going to be multiple tasks for each, first finding the BPM then actually manipulating each to match. Which should change, the faster or slower? What have you researched/tried already? i havent used the web audio API but this may help you understand the DSP involved. http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/time-pitch-overview/

Comment: I have the BPM of each track. For example one is 96BPM the other is 128BPM. It does not matter which should change, in fact it could be good to have a toggle to switch to the faster or slower.